# Filter scraped data based on Value (Python & Silenium Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I will scrape data use silenium web driver (python). But i don't want scrape all data instead I will scrape data that have value '5.654.876. Like picture in below

[result scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTpdh.jpg)

I use xpath to find element. I find xpath from right click in here and copy expath

[get expath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7PJ.jpg)

This Is my code :

```
NTA = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchResultContainer"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span') 
try:
    num_page_items = len(tanggal) 
    for i in range(num_page_items):
        print(tanggal[i].text + ' - ' + pulang[i].text + ' Harga ' +NTA[i].text)
    back = (back + delta) 
    start = (start + delta)  
except IndexError:
    pass
```

My question is, how can I get data but only have NTA 5,654,876 and pass other dates that don't have NTA 5,654,876?

I thought I had to modify the xpath but I didn't know what to do.

Comment: It would help if you could insert the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit] and even better if you can share the url. And can that value, 5,654,876 , change over time? Meaning are you after specific rows (for example), or are those values constant and you want to only return those? And is simply filtering your current result set based on this value an option?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. And please...no screenshots.